# When should "person" be preceded by "a" or "the"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

1. The king said that **the/a** person who shows kindness to people whenever they can will wear a crown of gold.
2. Our sergeant said that **the/a** student who works hard to improve will rise through the ranks.
3. The poor boy asked the king on behalf of **the/a** person who was devoted to the king …
4. At the award ceremony, it will be said to **the/a** person who received an award, “Stand up and sing.”

Questions

- Which article is correct to use in these sentences?
- Does the meaning change if I use either?
- What’s the difference?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47113/discussion-on-question-by-steppingstones-when-should-person-be-preceded-by-a).